# Make div span the entire width of the screen

Tags: html, css

Am trying to work with the `div` tag but it comes out like this:

[image]

On the left, you can see that it doesn't reach as far as the right.I have tried it in four different browsers so this isn't a browser problem.

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@page_title</title>
    <style>
        div {border: 3px solid black; width: 120%; margin: 1.2em; padding: 2em}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div">
        <h1>@page_title</h1>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting `width` to `120%`? A block-level element is 100% of the parent by default so you don't need to change the width.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7cc7efju/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <h1>@page_title</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 2em;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Margin tells the element how far it should be kept away from its neighboring elements and (in most cases) its parent.

So margin: 1.2em is pushing the div off from the left edge by this amount. First, remove that

Second: if you want a div to span the width of its container (in this case the body), then use `width:auto`. This will make its width be equal to the parents width, taking account of any margin or padding that are on the elements.

Comment: By the way, `width:auto` is also the default on block-level elements like `div`, so you can just drop the with-by-percentage part to get to this.

Comment: Yes, i deleted it already before trying the accepted answer.Thanks